# Angular 2 - ReplaySubject event is not retrieved by all subscribing components

Tags: events, angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

Have a little trouble with **ReplySubject**, **Observables** and **Subscribing** to these events.

In this service I create a Observable that triggers every 30 sec and pulls messages from an API, this is then

```
export class BspecReaderApiService {

  public MessageListObservable: Observable<MessageList>;
  public messageListReplySubject: ReplaySubject<MessageList>;

  constructor() {

    // set a messageList reply subject that returns an updated list of messages
    // every minute
    this.messageListReplySubject = new ReplaySubject<MessageList>(1);

    Observable.interval(30000).subscribe((i) => {
      if (this.messageAutoRefresh) {

        (...)

        // gets messages ml from API and trigger event
        this.messageListReplySubject.next(ml);

      }
    });

  }
```

This works well, then I have these three different components that subscribe to the replySubject like this:

MessageBox component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '.messagesBox',
  templateUrl: 'messages-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['messages-box.component.css'],
  providers: [BspecReaderApiService]
})
export class MessagesBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  public messageList: MessageList;

  constructor(private _bspec: BspecReaderApiService) {

    // subscribe to message list event
    console.log('messageBox subscribe to messageList');
    this._bspec.messageListReplySubject.subscribe(ml => {
      this.messageList = ml;
      console.log('messageBox received messageList', this.messageList);
    });
  }

  public ngOnInit() { }

}
```

app.component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  public messageList: MessageList;

  constructor(
    private _bspec: BspecReaderApiService,
  ) {

    (...)

    // subscribe to message list event
    console.log('app component subscribe to messageList');
    this._bspec.messageListReplySubject.subscribe(ml => {
      this.messageList = ml;
      console.log('app component received messageList', this.messageList);
    });
  }
```

ETC.

Now when I run the application I get in the console:

```
app.component.ts:37          app component subscribe to messageList
messages-box.component.ts:27 messageBox subscribe to messageList
home.component.ts:53         home component subscribe to messageList

(...) 

app component received messageList MessageList {newUser: false, startedSession: true, openedProject: false, messages: Array[0], diagnostics: Diagnostics…}
```

Here is the problem, only app component received messageList, not the other two components! Why does not all three components retrieve the messageList from the event?

**EDIT**

Some more info, here is my package.json with my angular version and rxjs version:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.1.23",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "ng2-cookies": "1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sweetalert2": "4.0.10",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.23"
  },
```

Comment: 3 things:
- what exact version of Angular2 are you using?
- what exact version of rxjs?
- `providers: [BspecReaderApiService]` should not be required
(and you have a typo in `messageListReplySubject` -> repl_a_ySubject)

Comment: Are you sure you're sharing the same instance of `BspecReaderApiService`? Check your providers.

Comment: @martin, you are both correct, I have the providers in app.component, and should remove it from the home.component, message-box.component etc. This fixed the problem!